# android notification only sound plays notification is not shown in notification drawer

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am trying to fire notification in at a particular time using AlarmManager and Notification manager. i am facing a strange problem. when notification is fired only sound plays but notification is not shown in the notification drawer.
i got an error in the log

```
04-26 11:32:09.217    1222-1222/? E/NotificationService﹕ WARNING: In a future release this will crash the app: com.example.shiv.selftweak
```

my code is .

The class which calls the AlarmManager

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FireNotification.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1000, intent1, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),  pendingIntent);
```

FireNotification class

```
public class FireNotification extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        long[] pattern = {0, 300, 0};
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1234, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Self tweak")
                .setContentText("Habbits are waiting for last dones")
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setAutoCancel(false);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());
    }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Android Menifest

```
 <service android:name=".FireNotification"></service>
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

when notification fires only sound plays. but it is not getting shown in the notification drawer which shows no notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't specified `mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)`.

Basically you have to set `smallIcon`, `contentTitle` and `contentText`. If you miss any of those the Notification will not be displayed at all! That's clearly specified [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification) (also you can read more about notifications there as well).

Comment: yes i also figured out the same. thanks. but android should throw an exception for same