# isolating what is causing NotificationService "In a future release this will crash the app" messages in logcat

Tags: android, compatibility, android-7.0-nougat

Since updating to Android N, I am now seeing the following message sometimes occurring in logcat:

```
NotificationService: WARNING: In a future release this will crash the app: ...
```

I have tried putting debug statements to isolate what I am doing that is causing this, but so far have been unsuccessful.  In addition, the message does not reliably reproduce under the original conditions in which it was observed.

In looking at the [changes in Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html), I don't see anything that appears to be applicable to this situation.

How can I determine what is causing the message?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874406/android-notification-only-sound-plays-notification-is-not-shown-in-notification), it can be answer on your question. Same error message.

Comment: @fearless Interesting... but does that answer apply when just trying to set the LED?

Comment: I did some research and yes, it can be the problem. Did you test it without LED functionality ? Same error message ? Can you add code how you create notification with LED.

Comment: @fearless I have a feeling that this is changing the question... which was about how to determine what is causing this message, whereas the answer presumes the NotificationManager instance I have found is the problem. I'm still have trouble reproducing the error messages (maybe they only display once per some qualification)